# Can't consistently select text when div currently has focus on input field

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Right now this problem only occurs for me in Microsoft Edge and IE11 (as one would expect, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all work like browsers that aren't terrible).

Basically imagine an instant messenger type of div - a `textarea` input field and above it is a `ul` with previously sent messages.

When this div is created, the `textarea` has focus (i.e. if you were to type, it would be accepted by the `textarea`). If I then try to double-click the text of the `li` elements that contain the previously sent messages, it does not consistently select the text and sometimes remains focused on the `textarea`. Selecting by dragging over the text always works, it is only double-click that does not. And the number of clicks it can take is consistent.

What could be causing this issue?